# Must click the next Text Widget to save the previous text content

Tags: java, text, swt

I used SWT to create a table, and in this table's forth column need to be editable, so I used TableEditor to make it. However every time I need to click the next Widget Text to save the content of previous text content. For example: in my table the forth column can be editable, 
I fill number in the first row forth column, I need to click the second row forth column, and only do this the content of Text of first row forth column can be saved.why? Follow is my
code:

```
final TableEditor editor=new TableEditor(table);
       editor.horizontalAlignment=SWT.LEFT;
       editor.grabHorizontal=true;
       final int EDITABLECOLUMN=3;

       table.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
              public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                // Clean up any previous editor control
                Control oldEditor = editor.getEditor();
                if (oldEditor != null)
                  oldEditor.dispose();

                // Identify the selected row
                TableItem item = (TableItem) e.item;
                if (item == null)
                  return;

                // The control that will be the editor must be a child of the
                // Table
                Text newEditor = new Text(table, SWT.NONE);
                newEditor.setText(item.getText(EDITABLECOLUMN));
                newEditor.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
                  public void modifyText(ModifyEvent me) {
                    Text text = (Text) editor.getEditor();
                    editor.getItem().setText(EDITABLECOLUMN, text.getText());
                  }
                });
                newEditor.selectAll();
                newEditor.setFocus();
                editor.setEditor(newEditor, item, EDITABLECOLUMN);
              }
            });
```

and my table created in this way:

```
public Table createTable(Composite parent){
        //表格布局
        GridData gridData=new GridData();
        gridData.horizontalAlignment=SWT.FILL;
        gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace=true;
        gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace=true;
        gridData.verticalAlignment=SWT.FILL;

        //创建表格，及其格式
       final Table table=new Table(parent,SWT.CHECK|SWT.MULTI|SWT.FULL_SELECTION|SWT.V_SCROLL|SWT.H_SCROLL);
       table.setHeaderVisible(true);
       table.setLayoutData(gridData);
       table.setLinesVisible(true);

       //创建表头
       String[] tableHeader={"Num","Package","Class","Run Times"};
       int[] tableColumnWidth={100,150,400,80};
       for(int i=0;i<tableHeader.length;i++){
           TableColumn tableColumn=new TableColumn(table,SWT.NONE|SWT.CENTER);
           tableColumn.setText(tableHeader[i]);            
           tableColumn.setMoveable(true);
           tableColumn.setWidth(tableColumnWidth[i]);
       }
        table.addListener(SWT.Selection, tableListener);              
    return table;
}
```

I changed the content of area where was marked as number one, this content only saved when I clicked area 2. It means only clicking area 2 to active the event:
[image: I changed the content of area where was marked as number one, this content only saved when I clicked area 2. It means only clicking area 2 to active the event]

Comment: Your problem is somewhat difficult to visualize - would you be able to share some screenshots or diagrams to help clarify?

Comment: hi~I re-edited my question and added a picture, I do not know whether I said clearly,thanks~

Comment: I have solved this problem, because I wrote **newEditor.addModifyListener** in table's listener, and got table data also in this listener, so I click the table, modified the text after I got the data. So I did not get the newest data

Comment: Excellent, Shine.  You should consider answering your own question in that case.